# Create button always on top

Tags: c#, wpf, button, always-on-top

I'm trying to make a `Button` always stay on top even after minimize the application. Quite like a floating `Button`, when I click the Button the application hide, click it again the application show.

Window can set the `Topmost="True"` property, what about the `Button`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make more one window with button, like this in XAML:

```
<Window AllowTransparency="True" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None"
        Topmost="True" ShowInTaskbar="False" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        Background="{x:Null}">
    <Button x:Name="HideShowButton" Content="Restore" />
</Window>
```

Button cannot exist without window, but with these properies window will be invisible.

Comment: Yeah, i got the idea, the code work perfectly. But i have tried this before, the only different is the Background="Transparent" and your's is "{x:Null}"
And where to put the second window? Inside or outside the original window?

Comment: Outside, just another window. You can create it from `App.OnStartup` (if you use it), or from any of your `MainWindow` methods (for example  `Loaded` event handler).